# Manipulating textarea value for in memory jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given an array of strings where each string is the html for a form element that has a value assigned, I'd like to loop over the array and remove the values for each element.

I need to end up with the same array of strings but where:

- `input` and `textarea` element values are all set to ''
- `select` element options are all deselected
- `checkbox` elements are all unchecked
- I set the element backgrounds to yellow just to show the text areas are being selected

To do this, I figured I'd wrap the elements in a div, set all the element attributes, then get the div's html.

This works for all the elements *except textareas*

I've tried

- `.val('')`
- `.attr('value', '')`
- `.prop('value', '')`

None worked to remove the value of a textarea in memory.

```js
var elements = [
  '<input type="checkbox" checked>',
  '<input type="text" value="1041">',
  '<input type="text" value="activities">',
  '<textarea>some text</textarea>',
  '<select><option value=""></option><option value="1" selected>1</option></select>',
  '<select><option value=""></option><option value="1" selected>1</option></select>',
  '<textarea>some text</textarea>'
];

var newElements = [];
$.each(elements, function(i, item) {
  var $temp = $('<div>').html(item);
  var $tempElements = $temp.find('input:not(.row-select), textarea, select').addClass('test');
  //$tempElements.val('');  // doesnt work at all
  $tempElements.attr('value',''); // works for text inputs but not textarea
  $tempElements.attr('checked', false);
  $tempElements.find('option').attr('selected', false);
  newElements.push($temp.html());
});

$('#result').html(newElements.join(''));
```

```css
.test{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

#### Expected result:

```
var elements = [
  '<input type="checkbox">',
  '<input type="text" value="1041">',
  '<input type="text" value="activities">',
  '<textarea>some text</textarea>',
  '<select><option value=""></option><option value="1" selected>1</option></select>',
  '<select><option value="" selected></option><option value="1">1</option></select>',
  '<textarea></textarea>'
];
```

#### [Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84dyccw0/4/)

I do understand that I could just append the html to a div in the dom and do what I need there, but Im curious if there isn't a way to do this in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.text('')` to remove the content of `textarea`.

```
$tempElements.text('');
```

And you don't need `prop` when using `attr` before.

```
// change
$tempElements.attr('value', '').prop('value', '');
// to
$tempElements.attr('value', '');
```

**[Wokring example.](https://jsfiddle.net/84dyccw0/6/)**

Comment: Fair enough. Any idea why this works in memory while the other methods fail?

Comment: You can even use `html('')` too. But it's a bit wrong here. `val` and `attr` will not work, because it is the content inside element, not an attribute on this state. @DelightedD0D

Comment: `.prop('value', '');` was just me trying different variations. `.text('')` didnt occur to me here. I'd still like to know why `.attr('value', '')` and `.val('')` dont work if anyone knows

Comment: It is not working because those set the **attr**ibute `value`. But those `textarea` don't have an attribute, they have contents. So it would not work. For better clarification: https://jsfiddle.net/84dyccw0/8/ take a look at the `textarea` with browser developer tools. You will see what `attr` does here. :) @DelightedD0D

Comment: Honestly im used to using `.val()` and I guess I just assumed `.attr` would also work. I still dont understand why `.val('');` doesnt work though, since it works fine once the element is in the dom : https://jsfiddle.net/84dyccw0/10/

Comment: `attr` with `value` will never work on `textarea`, because, as I told before, this elements don't have an attribute `value`. The value is the inner content of this element. `val()` is an intelligent wrapper. It tries to find the correct way to set the value. With `attr` for `inputs` and `text` for `textarea`. I'm not 100% sure why `val` is not working in detail. But I think jQuery can't get the details from the browser, because it is not in DOM already. So it will not get the correct information. And because of this it acts like `attr('value','')`, what is the fallback of `val()` @DelightedD0D

Answer (score 1):

`.attr('value', '')` and `.val('')` don't work because you're pushing the element's html and appending that, rather than the actual dom element/jquery object.

Comment: Im not sure I follow. I'm modifying the value of the jQuery object with `.val('')` then I'm getting the html. Shouldn't that html reflect those changes?

Comment: no because you're not changing the html, you're changing the properties of an object. `.attr()` only works with the other elements because they actually have those attributes in their html

Comment: Gotcha, I guess I just figured that jQuery understood the change and would modify the html property acordingly